# Can a Wizard use two spell books?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, wizard, spellcasting, equipment

So lets say I am playing a level 12 Wizard, and I am in a dungeon when I find a spell book. So something similar happened in a quest I was playing and then the my DM said something along the lines of "So you can copy the spells in the book to your own book and you will have to buy...". So this made me think must I copy these spells to use them or can carry around both spells and cast from them whenever I want? Am I limited to spells from my book or can I use all spell books for spells

Comment: I'm fairly certain this is a duplicate, but if your question is different, please clarify and we can reopen.

Comment: Okay, this helps, @NautArch!